# How to create animation image on hover?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, css-transitions

I have a graphic in XD that animated on hover. I want to implement it on my website.
This is similar to this screen capture [here](https://share.getcloudapp.com/jkuLyevJ)

I tried it using CSS transition but not working. Is there anyone who can help me to do this? My Code is below.

```
    <div class="graphic"></div>
    <style>
    .graphic{
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-image: url(images/Illustration-Idle.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        transition: background-image 5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .graphic:hover{
        background-image: url(images/Illustration-Hover.svg);
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Can you please post the code that you've tried so far ? It'd be difficult to guess what you're having trouble with, sans any code  :)

Comment: I added my code example in question @AkshAyAgrawal

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7aretodk/1/  Please check this fiddle. Your code seems to be working fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply class or Id to bull and arrow 'path' of svg. Then use transition on them. I would recommend put your SVG in div directly.

```
.bull{
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

svg:hover .bull{
  transform: translate(-50px, 50px);
}

.arrow{
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

svg:hover .arrow{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(50px,0);
}
```